# Communication between ESP01 Arduino NANO and using External Interrupt in Arduino NANO for other than communication program same time

Tags: arduino-nano

I have done communication between ESP01 and Arduino NANO (ATMEGA328 based). ESP pins used are GPIO-0 and GPIO2. In NANO, used D2 and D3. This program working Ok. Now I want to add external interrupt in my Arduino NANO program while continuing communication with ESP01. But I cannot use D2 and D3 because it was used by communication program. Now Arduino NANO's limit is it has only two interrupt pins which are D2 and D3. So if I use this for external interrupt program, I lose communication with ESP01. Can anybody help me to use my both task at the same time: Task1- External interrupt in Arduino Nano, Task2- Communication with ESP01. Your reply will help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use D2 and D3 for the communication? There's plenty of other pins on a Nano...

Comment: so move the SodtwareSerial to other pair of pins. 4 and 5 are good for PWM but 6 and 7 are not special.

Answer (score 2):

D2 and D3 Pins on Arduino nano support external Interrupt. Hence, you have to use one of those for the interrupt.

Since you are using `softwareSerial()` you can easily remap it to other digital pins of the Nano.

Pins from `D4-D12`can be used for communication.
You just have to change the parameters in the `softwareserial()` as below:

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(4, 5); // RX, TX;;for example
```

[image]

Comment: how do you know OP is using SoftwareSerial? it is not mentioned in the question. I made a wild guess in a comment